# Open-iSCSI Target IQN Naming Case

Tags: linux, sles, iscsi, ceph, targetcli

I'm using LRBD to configure iSCSI targets from a Ceph cluster, LRBD uses Open-iSCSI/targetcli to configure the targets.

When I use an uppercase letter in the unique part of the iqn (after the colon), I get the following error message:

```
Invalid iqn wwn: iqn.1996-10.com.suse:enVolume1
```

If I change the `V` to be lowercase, the target is successfully created.

I can't find any information which says the iqn cannot contain uppercase letters after the colon, does anyone know what's causing this?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with iSCSI, but I tried to setup a target with uppercase letters in the iqn on SLES with the yast module, it was converted to lowercase letters during discovery on the client side. So I guess it's probably recommended to use only lowercase and some tools convert that for you.